# Font Awesome icons don't show up in my HTML

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, font-awesome, responsive-design-view

I'm trying to make a Responsive header with **HTML** and **CSS**.
But there are two problems which I can't solve.

```js
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.navbar__toggleBtn');
const menu = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu');
const icons = document.querySelector('.navbar__icons');

toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menu.classList.toggle('active');
  icons.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Source Sans Pro;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #263343;
  padding: 8px 12px;
}

.navbar__logo {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
}

.navbar__logo i {
  color: #d49466;
}

.navbar__menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar__menu li {
  padding: 8px 12px;
}

.navbar__menu li:hover {
  background-color: #d49466;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.navbar__icons {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar__icons li {
  padding: 8px 12px;
}

.navbar__toggleBtn {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 32px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #d49466;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 8px 24px;
  }
  .navbar__menu {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar__menu li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar__icons {
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar__toggleBtn {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar__menu.active,
  .navbar__icons.active {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">
  <script src="main.js" defer></script>
  <title>Nav Bar</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar__logo">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-brain-circuit"></i>
      <a href="#">Macro</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="navbar__menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Supply</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar_icons">
        <li><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__toggleBtn">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

And these are the problem.

1. **I want to show my social icons but they don't show up.**
2. **Social icons don't disappear when the page shrinks.**

I tried to add the below code in my **style.css**.

```css
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But nothing changed. I have no idea how to fix them. How can I solve it?

Comment: You seem to be using fontawesome version 5 so search there for the icons you want. You will probably find fas or fab is required rather than fa-solid fa-brands which look more like version 6.

Answer (score 0):

You are using fontawesome v6 code with a v5 css.

In v5, the code should look like this:

```html
<i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
```

Remember to select v5 when you search for the icons.